# set iphone/ipod memory songs as ringtone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ringtone

Currently I am developing an app in which there is a requirement under which set iPhone/iPod memory 
song as ringtone in app.initially,I have add the default memory song of iPhone in my app table view 
with the help of `MPMediaPickerController`.Now I want to set selected song as ringtone for particular 
time interval.I have search my best, but did not find any solution.How to solve this?

Comment: accept answers to your previous posted question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not set Ringtone from your application. This feature is not supported in the API.